# hidden backstack fragments re-shown on configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation

I am building a one activity-multiple fragments application. I add to the backstack after every transaction. After a couple of hiding and showing fragments and then I rotate the phone,  all the fragments added on the container were restored and every fragment is on top of the other.

What can be the problem? Why is my activity showing the fragments I have previously hidden?

I am thinking of hiding all the previously-hidden-now-shown fragments but is there a more 'graceful' way of doing this?

Comment: Just to note, hidden fragments are already kept in the container as invisible. So changing configuration might possibly show them again since they're already in there.

Answer (score 9):

Use `setRetainInstance(true)` on each fragment and your problem will disappear.

**Warning:** setting this to true will change the Fragments life-cycle.

While `setRetainInstance(true)` resolves the issue, there may be cases where you don't want to use it.
To fix that, setup a boolean attribute on the Fragment and restore the visibility:

```
private boolean mVisible = true;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
    if (_savedInstanceState!=null) {
        mVisible = _savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mVisible");
    }
    if (!mVisible) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(this).commit();
    }
    // Hey! no setRetainInstance(true) used here.
}
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean _hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(_hidden);
    mVisible = !_hidden;
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle _outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(_outState);
    if (_outState!=null) {
        _outState.putBoolean("mVisible", mVisible);
    }
}
```

Once the configuration changes (e.g. screen orientation), the instance will be destroyed, but the Bundle will be stored and injected to the new Fragment instance.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. you should check source code in the function onCreateView() of your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){//for the first time

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        FragmentExample fragment = new FragmentExample();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_main, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }else{//savedInstanceState != null
        //for configuration change or Activity UI is destroyed by OS to get memory 
        //no need to add Fragment to container view R.id.layout_main again
        //because FragmentManager supported add the existed Fragment to R.id.layout_main if R.id.layout_main is existed.
        //here is one different between Fragment and View

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_main">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use the `replace()` function rather than hide and show. I had the same problem when I started using `Fragments` and using the replace function really helped manage the `Fragments` better. Here is a quick example:

```
fragmentManager.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, desiredFragment, DESIRED_FRAGMENT_TAG)                                   
               .addToBackStack(null)
               .commit();
```